# VueJS get AJAX data before routing / mounting componenents

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I want to initialize some base data once before having VueJS does any routing / mounting.

Now I found out about the Global Navigation Guard `router.beforeEach`. But It triggers not only on the initial load (page load), but every route that is triggered. Now I could put in some sort of `if-statement` to have the code run only once, but that's not my preferred way of solving this:

```
// pseudo:
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (state.initialized === false) {
        await store.dispatch(init)
    }

    // the rest of my routing guard logic....
})
```

I'd prefer not having the if-statement run everytime (knowing it's only going to be true once, and false forever after).

Is there an official way to have (ajax) code run only **once**, AFTER vue is initialized (so I have access to vuex state, etc.), BEFORE any routing has started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily perform an asynchronous task *before* mounting your root Vue instance.

For example

```js
// main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import store from 'path/to/your/store'
import router from 'path/to/your/router'
import App from './App.vue'

store.dispatch('init').then(() => {
  new Vue({
    store,
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('#app')
})
```

It would be a good idea to show something in `index.html` while that's loading, eg

```html
<div id="app">
  <!-- just an example, this will be replaced when Vue mounts -->
  <p>Loading...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the store was fully functional before creating the Vue instance.

Comment: Just wanted to thank for this information. Like OP, I did not know that store is fully created and ready to go before Vue instance is created.